# sql calculation and i did not solve

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table,

Stok  :

```
   Product_Code     Product_Name     Hand_Stock     Market_Stok
      121212           Soap              5               4
      131313           Cake              8               8
      141414           Banana            0               0
```

Campaign :

```
   Campaign_Name     Product_Code     Product_Name     Quantity
      Camp1             121212            Soap            6
      Camp2             131313            Cake            3
      Camp1             131313            Cake            4
      Camp1             141414           Banana           5
```

I want to bring "Camp1" informations with looking to Stock total quantity (Hand + Market) > 1 , WHERE campaing.Product_Code = stok.Product_Code

I mean, if i have 300 products in Camp1 and 150 products in 300 products (hand + market) stock = 0, I did not want to see this 150 products.

By the way, a product in Campaign can be belong more than one campaign.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM Stok
INNER JOIN Campaign
ON Stok.Product_Code=Campaign.Product_Code
WHERE (Stok.Hand + Stok.Market) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM Stok s INNER JOIN Campaign c ON s.Product_Code=c.Product_Code WHERE (s.Hand_Stock + s.Market_Stok) > 1

Try this

Comment: I solved, the problem come from different types of (utf8_general, utf8_turkish_ci) Product_Code